# I can't add a new field to my document using MongoDB with Next.js

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js

I want to add a new field (company) to my document. My entire API is:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../utils/mongodb";
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'


export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const { name } = req.body

  const session = await getSession({ req });

  const a = await db
    .collection("users").update({"_id": session.id},{$set: {company: { general: {name: req.body.name} }}})
};
```

But the document isn't updating.

Current document:

```
{
_id: "id"
name: "Test"
email: "test@somemmmail.com"
image: "..."
createdAt: "2020-10-29T16:25:08.908+00:00"
updatedAt: "2020-10-29T16:25:08.908+00:00"
}
```

But I want to add a company field:

```
{
    _id: "id"
    name: "Test"
    email: "test@somemmmail.com"
    image: "..."
    createdAt: "2020-10-29T16:25:08.908+00:00"
    updatedAt: "2020-10-29T16:25:08.908+00:00"
    company: [{general: "someinfo"}]
    }
```

I am using Next.js & MongoDB package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to convert the `session.id` string to a mongo `ObjectId(session.id)` object:

Take a look at this screenshot using [mongo shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sobOu.png):

**No results:**

```
db.users.find({ "_id": "5fa1e18be3a0523e5ce6c50f" })
```

**Found match:**

```
db.users.find({ "_id": ObjectId("5fa1e18be3a0523e5ce6c50f") })
```

On that note, since you're only looking for **one** document to update, I'd recommend [findOne](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOne) over [find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find).